# javax.net.ssl.sslhandshakeexception remotehost terminated the handshake

Tags: java, java-8, azul-zulu

After running this command

```
pyspark  --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.1.0,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.1,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.8.1 --conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog" --driver-memory 100g --jars file:///C:/hadoop/jars/hadoop-azure-3.3.2.jar,file:///C:/hadoop/jars/wildfly-openssl-java-2.2.1.Final
```

I received the following error:

```
     :::: ERRORS
                Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.1.0/delta-core_2.12-2.1.0.pom 
(javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake)
                Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.1.0/delta-core_2.12-2.1.0.jar 
    (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake)
                Server access error at url https://repos.spark-packages.org/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.1.0/delta-core_2.12-2.1.0.pom 
    (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake)
                Server access error at url https://repos.spark-packages.org/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/2.1.0/delta-core_2.12-2.1.0.jar 
(javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake)
```

Maybe interesting for you: I can open URLs in my browser.

As I have read in some posts. The reason could be the TLS version mismatch. What should I do to resolve this issue? I will be really appreciated it if you can show me a step-to-step setting

****UPDATE****

The

- server ("https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io") uses TLS1.2
- I removed TLS1.2 and TLS1.1 from `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`in the `java.security` file`

But still receive the handshake problem

Comment: which java version do you use? Can you try openjdk11 to make sure tls1.3 is supported?

Comment: `openjdk version 1.8.0_345` and  `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.64.0.19-CA-win64)`